# SSRS Trying to add a page break between 2 Subreports which are grouped in parent.rdl

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

So I have a report that I was able to get almost exactly how I wanted it, but I can't manage to get a page break between the 2 subreports.  Help would be highly appreciated.

I have 3 reports

1. PARENT.rdl
2. SUBREPORT_1.rdl
3. SUBREPORT_2.rdl

SUBREPORT_1 and SUBREPORT_2 share a common field (for example city) so I'm able to group them inside the PARENT.rdl so it has this type of format:

What I have looks like this:

```
SUBREPORT_1: MIAMI

SUBREPORT_2: MIAMI

----- page break ------

SUBREPORT_1: ORLANDO

SUBREPORT_2: ORLANDO

----- page break ------

SUBREPORT_1: TAMPA

SUBREPORT_2: TAMPA
```

I have all of this working perfectly, **my only problem is I'd like to add a page break between SUBREPORT_1 and SUBREPORT_2**.  There is already a page break at the end of the City grouping.  I want it to look like:

```
SUBREPORT_1: MIAMI     
   -- page break --       << add this
SUBREPORT_2: MIAMI

----- page break ------

SUBREPORT_1: ORLANDO
   -- page break --       << add this
SUBREPORT_2: ORLANDO

----- page break ------

SUBREPORT_1: TAMPA
   -- page break --       << add this
SUBREPORT_2: TAMPA
```

I've tried putting the subreports in rectangles inside of the tablix cells, but no luck.  I'm assuming because of the PARENT tablix can't be broken up mid-tablix ?

Any help with this would be great, of if there is a better solution than the subreport method.  That is what I found in my research.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you placed your subreport inside the rectangle did you check the subreport properties to make sure the Parent under the "other" in properties was the rectangle? If it isnt you'll need to drag the subreport out of the rectangle and then back into it so it becomes the parent item then set the rectangle to have a page break.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.  Yes I just double checked and yes both subreports have the proper parent rectangle in the "other" section.  I've tried them in different tablix row cells, as well as the same row cell with no luck.  I've checked off "page break after" on the first subreport/rectangle AND "page break before" on the second one - still with no luck!  I'm not sure what else I can try

Comment: can toy post a picture of your tablix?

Comment: Ah i see now, create a page break in the parent group on the City.

Comment: Hey not sure if I understand.  I have a page break at the end of each parent group (city).  However I can't get the page break between subreport1 and subreport2.  Each city displays both subreports, thanks for staying with me here!

Comment: I think I got it.  I put a page break on the details group, after each instance.  thanks

Comment: Np, I would answer it and then mark it answered so it doesn't remain in the queue.